# How to get OpenCL working on an ATI Radeon card

Tags: linux, opencl

I'm trying to compile [dolphin](http://www.dolphin-emu.com/news.php), a Nintendo emulator.  I downloaded the trunk and it compiled fine but it won't link.  Instead, I get this error:

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../../Binaries/plugins/libPlugin_VideoOGL.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenCL
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Binaries/plugins/libPlugin_VideoOGL.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Source/Plugins/Plugin_VideoOGL/CMakeFiles/Plugin_VideoOGL.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It looks like I need some sort of OpenCL library.  I did some research and somehow had an idea that I needed to install fglrx.  It did not go smoothly.  In fact, when I tried to run fglrxinfo, I got a seg fault..nice.  My video wasn't totally hosed, so I tried a make and got the same OpenCL error above.  I just want to get Dolphin working.  What are my options?

Here are my specs:

- Ubuntu 10.4
- Radeon X1200 (RS690M)

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the ATI Stream SDK. I think ubuntu 10.10 includes the packages, if not, you can find the installed [here](http://developer.amd.com/gpu/ATIStreamSDK/Pages/default.aspx).

Also your GPU doesn't support OpenCL, so you will get only the CPU OpenCL device, without much performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Although your card doesn't support OpenCL, the answer to the question is that you need to have libOpenCL.so in /usr/lib/.

-lOpenCL is a flag being passed to linker telling it to link against the OpenCL library.

This library is included in both the ATI Stream SDK (for ATI users) and the NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK (for NVIDIA users).