# PyOpenCL can't find include files when installed via "easy_install."

Tags: python, cuda, opencl, easy-install

so I've downloaded the nVidia CUDA libraries and put them in the default location:

```
/usr/local/cuda
```

When I go to run this:

```
sudo easy_install pyopencl
```

It gives me this error:

```
In file included from src/wrapper/wrap_cl.cpp:1:0:
src/wrapper/wrap_cl.hpp:20:19: fatal error: CL/cl.h: No such file or directory
```

I can, however, verify that the above file *does* exist along with several other header files:

```
/usr/local/cuda/include/CL/cl.h
```

I've even tried setting the LD_LIBRATH_PATH:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib
```

But it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compiler's include path probably doesn't include /usr/local/cuda/include/. The environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH is actually there to tell the compiler/runtime environment where to find shared object files. There are two ways (that know of) to fix this:

1) Most compilers accept a flag that specifies an addition to the include path; for gcc, it's -I, so

```
gcc -I /usr/local/cuda/include [code files, more options, etc]
```

will tell gcc to look for includes in /usr/local/cuda/include, in addition to the system include path

2) Link the OpenCL header files into your system include path (usually /usr/include/).
Something like:

```
# ln -s /usr/local/cuda/include/CL CL
```

executed from within the directory /usr/include should work.

If after fixing this problem, you have a problem like the following:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenCL
```

then you might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161195/how-to-get-opencl-working-on-an-ati-radeon-card/4424806#4424806).

Comment: That did it, thanks so much!  And yep-- I had to do the additional step in the link provided.  It's installed and working.  Thanks!